# Exim: Log sent/received emails headers

Tags: logs, email, exim

I've a fully working mail server running on Exim over Debian. Recently I was asked if it was possible to get a monthly log of the headers of all email sent and received. By headers I mean email addresses that are on the `to`, `from`, `cc`, `bcc` headers.

The ideia is to generate a log that contains all the emails on those headers without distinguishing from send/received wtv, like this:

```
email1@server.dev
email2@server2.dev
emailaaa@server3.dev
```

So one email peer line. So I decided to give a try to `grep` and come up with this:

```
grep -E -o "\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b" exim_mainlog.txt > emails.txt
```

It does output all emails on that file, however I get a bunch of garbage, like email ids: `20151220030229.333FA10F392@xxxx.dev` and attempts from spammers to deliver emails to inexistent accounts on the server.

What the best way (and how can I do it) to get the clean list, basically an email to be valid it would need to check the following rules:

1. Valid email address;
2. Is the origin of email that was correctly
   delivered to some account on the server;
3. Is the destination
   (including `cc` or `bcc`) to somewhere else and was delivered
   correctly;
4. Not bounce

Can this be done by analyzing server logs? Or maybe a filter on email server? Either way, how?

Thank you!